# Powershell forcing reload for using module

Tags: powershell, powershell-v5.1

Is there a way to force PowerShell to reload a module when `using module .\MyModule.psm1`?

Normally I would use `Import-Module .\MyModule.psm1 -Force` but since I am using `enum` and `class` C# style this won't do; since `enum` and `class` are not visible outside the module if I use `Import-Module`.

I cannot use first `Import-Module` and then `using module` as `using module` must be on first row.

My PSVersion is 5.1.14409.1005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid there is currently no solution (as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 7.2), but one is being proposed for PowerShell *Core* in [GitHub issue #7654](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7654).

Additionally, as you observe yourself, the linked issue...

> includes further links with discussion, uservoice item and comments about difference between PS and PSCore and some more comments about `using` vs `Import-Module` language-design wise.